# Scala Worksheet in IntelliJ gives "no module classpath specified"

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am setting up a project with the following structure:

```
project
project/frontend: HTML and Javascript stuff
project/backend: Scala - this contains build.sbt
```

I *believe* the folder structure is the problem. When I have a project without these sub-folders, IntelliJ works well. Now that I have these sub-folders (and open Intellij in the `project` super-folder), any run of a Scala worksheet gives me the error of  "No module classpath specified". Would you have suggestions for fixing this? I simply don't know what to do to specify a classpath.

IntelliJ version: 2022.1.2, Build #IU-221.5787.30

See Worksheet settings:[image]

Comment: You should have the sbt project (the proper build) and the sbt build-project inside of it. Your sbt project seems to be project/backend - no project. Have a look here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sbt-support.html#sbt_structure
Maybe a quick fix would be to open your Scala project directly in project/backed.

Comment: Thanks! The link describes that this is the default structure, but it's not clear to me whether this structure is *required*.

I agree that this quick fix would work, but I'd want to have a way of using IntelliJ at the root folder, because I use IntelliJ to coordinate a number of scripts that carry across the project (e.g. deploy scripts that integrate javascript tests). I'm assuming that IntelliJ allows this, and at least I'd want to confirm whether that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by adjusting the **content root for modules**:

1. Click on "File"->"Project Structure"
2. In the Project Structure Modal, click on "Project Settings"->"Modules"
3. Adjust the content root, setting it to "backend" (you might have to remove the default content root to do that).

This also fixes a bunch of other issues, e.g. the IDE detecting and linking objects correctly.

[image]

[image]

[image]